# Project reactor: How to retry mono with different argument until some condition is met

Tags: java, asynchronous, project-reactor

I need to generate unique code asynchronously with project reactor.

Method signature looks like this:

```
public Mono<String> generateCode()
```

So the flow should be like this:

1. Generate random code
2. Check if this code exists in the database
3. If exists, re-generate the code (step 1) and check it again (step2)
4. If the code is unique, return it

My current solution is to call generateCode recursively like this:

```
 Mono<String> generateCode() {
    String code = generateCodeValue();
    return emailConfirmationRepository
        .findByCode(code)
        .flatMap(codeOpt -> codeOpt.map(c -> generateCode()).orElseGet(() -> Mono.just(code)));
  }
```

But I don't like this, because each call creates its own stack and this can lead to StackOverflowError.

I know, there should be a very large amount of calls, it most likely will not happen, but still, I need a solution without recursion, like a plain while loop, but with async code.

How can I achieve this with reactor?

Comment: You can use any variant of retry - https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#retry--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retry it UNTIL SOME CONDITION IS MET indefinitely you shall:

```
Mono<String> generateCode() {
return Mono.fromCallable(() -> generateCodeValue())
        .flatMap(code -> emailConfirmationRepository
                .findByCode(code)
                .flatMap(codeOpt -> codeOpt
                        .map(c -> Mono.<String>error(new CodeAlreadyExistsException()))
                        .orElseGet(() -> Mono.just(code))))
        .retry(CodeAlreadyExistsException.class::isInstance)
}

class CodeAlreadyExistsException extends RuntimeException {}
```

Thanks @alexander-pankin.

Comment: Thanks, @RodneyZ, it's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 3):

Note, though, that retry will retry all of your steps. So, if you have a more complicated code, like:

```
Mono<String> generateCode() {
return Mono.fromCallable(() -> generateCodeValue())
        .flatMap(code -> doSomeExpensiveOperation1())
        .flatMap(code -> doSomeDangerousOperation2())
        .flatMap(code -> emailConfirmationRepository
                .findByCode(code)
                .flatMap(codeOpt -> codeOpt
                        .map(c -> Mono.<String>error(new CodeAlreadyExistsException()))
                        .orElseGet(() -> Mono.just(code))))
        .retry(5);
}
class CodeAlreadyExistsException extends RuntimeException {}
```

Then all of your steps before "findByCode" will be repeated again, including doSomeExpensiveOperation1 and doSomeDangerousOperation2.

Comment: Though it will do the job, but I'm curious how to retry it UNTIL SOME CONDITION IS MET (without retry limit)

Comment: @RodneyZ is there a way to only retry one "previous" operation in chain?

Answer (score 0):

You could return error `Mono` when given code exists and use `retry` operator.

```
Mono<String> generateCode() {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> generateCodeValue())
            .flatMap(code -> emailConfirmationRepository
                    .findByCode(code)
                    .flatMap(codeOpt -> codeOpt
                            .map(c -> Mono.<String>error(new CodeAlreadyExistsException()))
                            .orElseGet(() -> Mono.just(code))))
            .retry(5);
}

class CodeAlreadyExistsException extends RuntimeException {}
```